# Как импортировать makeStyles в material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Пытаюсь подключить следующим образом:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.jsx 10:0-54

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/styles' in 'C:\Users\bymbv\Desktop\materialui\src'
```

Пытался по другому накатить пакет, заново устанавливать зависимости, но безуспешно.

Comment: никак. Устарело с выходом 5 версии. https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/

Comment: Понял. Спасибо большое!